# C#: Initialize HttpPostedFileBase from a file path (string)

Tags: c#, file, path, httppostedfilebase

I have a path (stored as a string) - eg `\\documents\doc1.txt`. I am trying to initialize a variable of type HttpPostedFileBase with the file represented by the string path. How can I do that please?
 I have looked at method like

```
 Model.File[count] = File.Open(item.PictureDirectory, FileMode.Open);
```

but these return  System.io.filestream objects.

```
FileStream file = File.OpenRead(filepath);
```

But how can I convert this to an httppostedfilebase?

I am trying to do exactly what is posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12672447/807223)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, as in the other question link to, having a method that requires a `HttpPostedFileBase` as an input, and then requires you to send a file *not* automatically transferred as a `HttpPostedFileBase`, suggests you need to refactor the method. In the example by Pommy, perhaps an input of `Stream` would be more appropriate?

Now, if you absolutely must have an instance of `HttpPostedFileBase`, here's what you're up against. [The class is abstract](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfilebase.aspx), so you're never going to construct it directly. Instead you'll need to construct an inheriting class. Within the standard libraries, `HttpPostedFileWrapper` inherits, and takes `HttpPostedFile` as a [constructor input](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfilewrapper.httppostedfilewrapper.aspx).

But here's the rub, the constructor for `HttpPostedFile` is internal, so outside of the System.Web library, you're not constructing an instance directly.

Your options then, are:

1. Find a factory, or some other method in System.Web that will construct a HttpPostedFile instance for you (my suspicion is you won't find that).
2. Implement your own inheriting class of base `HttpPostedFileBase`. This should be simple enough, it's only a small class, and depending on your code making use of it, you might not even have to implement all methods.
3. My recommended approach, if possible - Refactor your code to *not* use `HttpPostedFileBase`, and go with, say, `Stream` instead.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I am using an html file uploader to upload and display uploaded files. As you know, for security purposes, the path of the file is not shown when I simply display an existing path. Unfortunately, when looping through the files, the look does not seem to read the files that were preloaded in the file uploader. So far, I read the files using an HttpPostedFileBase So having the path, I was looking for a way to initialize the httppostedfilebase that is read by the loop.

Comment: So you're saying you have a loop that displays a list of file names, based on a collection of HttpPostedFileBase instances? Why not just change the loop to take a list of file names as input?

Comment: I will give that a try. I have a view with a number of file uploaders. Some are pre-loaded with files and others are not. The loop foes through all the files to grab them. I tried Httppostedfilesbase first because most resources on the web use this file type for file uploads.